# Is there a history of a country stealing medical supplies?

Tags: covid-19, medical-myths, medical-ethics, ppe

Today the [Whitehouse asked 3M](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-52161032) to stop shipments to Canada for protection from SARS-Cov2.

That seems like a bad idea because Canada *could* retaliate by cutting off water, electricity, oil, natural gas and food shipments to the USA along with closing the borders to USA with Raw Materials needed for USA Finished Goods production. Plus Canada might expand silk road to China through Russia over Arctic. Alth9ough Canada has no known nuclear weapons both Russia and China do. From personal experiences Frenemies are uncomfortable.

Besides that fact the UN General Assembly voted down a resolution to remove sanctions against US targeted countries today. So it's like NYC will get what she deserves.

But I wonder besides America taking [500,000 test kits](https://cdn.defenseone.com/a/defenseone/interstitial.html?v=9.16.0&rf=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.defenseone.com%2Fthreats%2F2020%2F03%2Fus-air-force-flew-half-million-coronavirus-test-kits-italy-tennessee%2F163879%2F) out of Italy is there a history of Countries hoarding / stealing medical supplies?

With the lack of greenhouse gases an Ice Age may come and Canada can ship oil and natural gas direct to China over Arctic (via Russia) to China in exchange for 5G and Walmart supplies so why would USA even consider such a folly? Let's not forget the fact USA is more focused on saving the Stock Market (read "FIAT" currency") rather than the people. Sure most humans are redundant "create work" projects but some of us are still necessary.

On a side note first Python program started in fall 2019 is called `mmm` fpr "Multiple Monitors Manager". Coincidentally it is also stock ticker for 3M which stands for "Minnesota Mining and Manufacturing" corporation.

Also consider the fact NJ Police have been authorized to steal 3M supplies from and similar [`PPE`](https://www.politico.com/states/new-jersey/story/2020/04/02/murphy-authorizes-state-police-to-commandeer-medical-supplies-in-coronavirus-fight-1270929) from warehouses today. I just gave a 3M mask to an ETS bus driver today worried because she has no protection. USA can invoke the Defense Protection Act but Canada can invoke the War Measures Act. In 1812 Canada burned down the White House so history exists.

The main question is: Has stealing of medical supplies happened in previous pandemics like Novel Coronavirus and can you cite sources?

As an aside it's sad I'm spending my time asking this question rather than posting answers. I think all the politicians should be silent like the leader of China Xi Jinping and let the experts and internet speak. Final thought the Captain of the Aircraft Carrier Roosevelt in Dire Straits (no song or pun intended) should be applauded and not reprimanded. I think the Pentagon and CIA (who reported China lied, just like Iraq WMD's) should be given notice to shape up or ship out.

In grade two they taught us how to sew and I sewed a mask by hand on my "staycation" last week. It's not rocket science but if you believe flying to mars and building a base to escape pollution on earth is the answer well, all the power to you and your not-a-god-religion.

I know it is reported in the 90's US killed millions of Iraqi's via medical sanctions but to recap; ***Is stealing of life saving medical supplies traditional?***

Comment: Is there a history SE that this can be migrated to?

Comment: @GrahamChiu Good question. However consider the fact the last Pandemic on this scale was WWI which was the war to end all wars which was focussed on bombing people and did not involve stealing of 3M or other PPE. Back then it was rather low tech. My hunch is there is no history of stealing life saving devices only a history of killing. But I would appreciate to hear an answer of stealing life saving devices at the risk of killing others. I guess that is called psychology or sociology. FTR I don't think 3M will listen to White House unless at gun point.

Comment: @GrahamChiu I read your profile just now. Being in NZ I think your Prime Minister would fund an endeavor to launch 15 minute anitbody test to clear people to go back to work. You could make $63 NZD or AUD and it's not rocket science to [test](https://dfw.cbslocal.com/video/4501840-fort-worth-lab-can-test-if-people-who-never-showed-coronavirus-symptoms-were-infected/) Your profile says you're a physician and this looks like a test someone in grade 2 could do. The more people NZ takes out of isolation the better! Although your PM was quick to implement 14 day quarantine she wasn't quick enough.

Comment: She certainly wasn't quick enough.  the medical profession had to petition her to go straight to lockdown.  What's the point of an antibody test?  Our PCR testing has not picked up any asymptomatic cases , and it means pretty much all of us are not immune

Comment: @GrahamChiu Well she did make NZ faster than AU but everyone was slower than CN which benefited from already being a surveillance state. I believe antibody testing will become a hot topic in western media this coming week. Personally I like the fact it's a 15 minute test and you could simply perform it on all passengers awaiting a flight. Unlike the evasive nasal swap it's a simple finger blood prick. But I've been promoting this for a month and don't want to turn into a soap box prophet on this single tool in our toolboxes. We still need conventional testing, tracing, treating and isolating.